# Create a custom info window in google maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

I'm trying to make a custom window that look like that (for map objects).

[image: User profile]

But instead of the project following and follower I wanna place an image, but I can't figure out how to make one, any refferes?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

its just an xml layout like other layouts would be. check [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/01/create-custom-info-contents-for-by.html) for a small tutorial.

Just remember that buttons in the layout will not work

Comment: To also get buttons to work, i also use it in my app:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go/15040761#15040761

Comment: A better tutorial can be found here: https://www.zoftino.com/google-maps-android-custom-info-window-example

Answer (score 6):

Read this post to understand [how to create custom infowindows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391445/multiple-line-or-break-line-in-snippet-google-maps-apiv2/17393978#17393978). You can add the required imageviews inside the xml layout file and render the layout as the infowindow

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the InfoWindow:

1. Make a custom InfoWindowAdapter (make sure to send the context) by overriding the the required methods.
2. Inflate the custom view.
3. Refer all the views by findViewById() and do that every needed.
4. Set the Adapter Like this :

mMap = googleMap;
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter getApplicationContext()));