# Custom View as custum marker on map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a custom View object (extends View) with own draw function. I use it in list of items in ListView with my custom adapter. I would like to use it on map also. How can I crate map marker from instance of my view object?
I think it have to be simple, but I can't find right way myself, and deadline is hot.

Thank in advance.
Rado.

Comment: Check this [earlier post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391445/multiple-line-or-break-line-in-snippet-google-maps-apiv2/17393978#17393978) for  a suitable method

Comment: @tony This is not what this question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create `Bitmap` from `View` you need to measure, layout and draw it youself onto `Canvas`.

This code will help you get to the point: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/ui/BubbleIconFactory.java#L60. Take a look at the `makeIcon` method there. `"One code is more than 1000 comments."`

Comment: Thank for your answer. But at that sample is process of making view from layout or from resource. I don't need that case. I already have a my own custom view with own onDraw function, where I use an canvas and draw functions. So I need only transform that view to bitmap. But your answer show me the right direction, where I have to find how to change view to bitmap. I find it for example here: http://code.neenbedankt.com/how-to-render-an-android-view-to-a-bitmap/