# How to add a view at particular position with click at runtime

Tags: android, google-maps

[image]

i have a map-view v2, running as i expected.

I have add a marker and getting infoWindow by clicking on marker. See the pic above

My problem is , I am not able to add a view beside the marker after clicking InfoWindow.

I am using setOnInfoWindowClickListener

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            int[] location = new int[2];
            getView().getLocationOnScreen(location);
            Log.e(TAG, "location=========="+location[0]+" , "+location[1]);
            final View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_window, null, false);
        }
    });
```

I want a view or window to right side of markerm , like ...

[image]

Comment: If it is with the purpos of adding contextual buttons, then how about using the ActionBar? Perhaps even with the overlay it provides for special actions, like the build in copy/cut/paste on textviews.

Comment: @cYrixmorten , I am not getting you

Comment: please suggest me , thnkyou

Comment: Please check if [using a custom infowindow adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391445/multiple-line-or-break-line-in-snippet-google-maps-apiv2/17393978#17393978) serves your purpose.

Comment: Have not yet tried to make my own custom InfoWindow yet, so cannot advice on much that. But as I recall it involved a Custom InfoWindow and did not require inflater.

Comment: BubbleIconFactory from Android Map Utility Library might help: http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for reply,  i want to add a one more view after cliking on default infoWindow, which should be right side of a marker.