# How to custom Marker and InfoWindow in google map android

Tags: android, android-layout

i try to custom a marker and an infowindow like this, but i don't know key word. Pls help me

[image]

And a little problem with a button to show side menu. How can i make a curve like that??

Comment: [Custom Info Window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393978/7130121) and [Custom Marker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14812104/7130121)